# Newsletter Mail not sending in Magento

Tags: magento, newsletter, magento-1.6

I am using Magento ver-1.6. I created few Newsletter Queue and set a feature date, but it does not send mail on that date. The status are also in **Not Sent** status. Any one knows what was the problem.

Comment: any info in magento's `var/logs` or details on how your sending mail via SMTP or local mail services?

Comment: Have you setup a cron job to hit cron.php? :)

Comment: Yes, Now the mails are sending through cron, But I want to know what was the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the real problem, now mails are sending through cron file.